# 1067 error on attempt to start MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

I've installed MySQL on Windows 7. When I'm trying to start MySQL service I'm getting error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly. Log message:

```
101111 22:27:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
101111 22:27:11 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 0 37356
101111 22:27:11  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 44233
101111 22:27:11  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
101111 22:27:12  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
101111 22:27:12 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution was to install MySQL without spaces in installation path.
Windows 7, 64-bit

Answer (score 21):

One more thing that prevents the mysqld windows service from running is if you have mysqld.exe already running (but not as a service) and occupying port 3306. When the service tries to start and sees that port 3306 is already taken, it fails.

Just open up the windows task manager and look for "mysqld.exe" under the Processes tab. If you see it, kill it and then try to start the service again.

```
c:\> net start [servicename]
```

example: c:\> net start MySQL

Comment: For me, there was nothing running on port 3306. To start MySQL, all I needed is to go to the "services" tab in Task Manager, find MySQL, and click "start".

Answer (score 14):

My issue happened right after a power failure. I got the error 1067 The process terminated unexpectedly. MySQL needless to say did not start. The answer was simple

1. Open mysql path\data
2. Remove (delete) both ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.
3. Start the service

Comment: In my case, the path to \data was not accessible because the drive was not available. This also resulted in a 1067 error.

Comment: This did it for me, too, after an unexpected shutdown of a Hyper-V Windows 2012 Server. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Me funcionó para windows server 2012 muchas gracias

Answer (score 12):

The solution to the problem for me was looking in my install directory, finding the /data folder, and copying it's content to the data folder that was specified in my .ini/.cnf configuration file.

Comment: Your solution pointed my out to the solution for me: update my .ini/.cnf configuration file, to point to the correct "data" dir. Thank you!

Comment: CORRECT. I had to move the contents of "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data" to "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data". Instantly worked, this is something the installer should have done.

Comment: Setting the paths in the my.ini file worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered a similar issue and I found that it is a permission problem. When I copy the database "data", I have to add the permission for "NETWORK SERVICE"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was "user error" (although the Windows installer should have been smarter about it and prevented me from committing such an error).

During installation, if you make changes to the default installation paths, make sure you use the same paths for both the "Server data files" on the Custom Setup screen and then later in the "InnoDB Tablespace Settings" during the "MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard"

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem changing the datadir in my.ini for Windows 7.

I wanted the data to be stored on a different drive and I was moving this data from another PC by copying the whole folder. I changed datadir to desired drive and saved the my.ini file with no problems.

But mysql would not start. I opened my.ini file again and it appeared to have been changed.
Then, I noticed the date on the my.ini had not changed. So I had to change the security privileges to give me write access to it.

This time when I saved it, the date changed and mysql started up access to all the correct data.

Answer (score 2):

Also check if all dirs which you wrote in the `my.ini` exists.

My problem was that `tmpdir` doeesn`t exist so MySQL daemon falls with error 1067.

```
[mysqld]
port= 3306
tmpdir = "C:/tmp"
```

In this case `C:/tmp` must exists.

Comment: This was my problem. I resized my cloud virtual machine and in doing so, my temp folder was gone. Recreating that folder fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Before messing with too much things, please check the user the service is trying to run as. In my case it was NETWORK this one did not have write permissions to some locations where it was needed. Changing the user to Local System Account did the trick. 
If the event viewer shows any error like **"Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\XXX.lower-test"**, there is a high probability for this solution to work.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have mysql data folder replaced by a windows directory junction.
I suspect ib_logfile0/1 and/or ibdata1 is corrupted.

Just try to delete those files and computername.err. Then restart mysql service.
That's what I did, with success.

Copying ibdata1 files, after a full reinstallation of mysql, to the junction dir and replacing dir by the junction, restarting mysql, was not enough.

You have to let mysql rebuild those files.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini"

The datadir line in my.ini should specify a path. Check the contents of that datadir path. Does it contain a folder named "mysql" and another folder named "test"?

If not, here are two choices:

1. Change the datadir line in my.ini to the correct location. This will probably be C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data
2. Clean out the existing contents of your datadir path. Copy the contents of the C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data to your datadir path. Restarting the mysql service should rebuild your empty database.

Comment: I should clarify that this error happens when MySQL cannot find its database tables. The datadir line in my.ini specifies the location of the MySQL database tables folder. The MySQL database folder should contain at least an ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 file, and also a subfolder named mysql. That mysql subfolder should contain a bunch of files with .frm, .MYD, and .MYI file extensions.

In fact, the error message "Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist" is complaining about the file mysql\hosts.frm being missing.

Comment: Also, the path to the my.ini file is actually specified in the properties for the MySQL service, in the "--defaults-file" command line argument for the MySQL service. You can check that value by typing "sc qc mysql" (without quotes) at the command prompt. The  service command line is in the BINARY_PATH_NAME section.

Answer (score 0):

In my instance it had nothing to do with spaces in the file name. I used the MSI installer custom configuration and opted to exclude the default databases, assuming it was just something like Northwind/Adventureworks. Nope, it includes the core MySql system database... once I added that to the installation it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same errors.  Similar approach for me.  From what I can tell, there is something weird going on with the reference to the `datadir` in the `my.ini` file.  Even when I manually edited it I could not seem to have any effect on it, until I blew EVERYTHING AWAY.  Wish I had better news...do a DB backup first.

For me the key to getting this to work was:

1) Remove the previous installation from `settings->control panel`.  Restart your machine.

2) Once machine comes back up, forcefully delete the previous installation directory. 
   [mine is `C:\apps\MySQL\MySQLServer-5.5\`, as I REFUSE to use `c:\program files\..`]

3) Forcefully delete the previous datadir directory [mine was `c:\data\mysql`].

4) Forcefully delete the previous default data directory [`C:\Documents` and `Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL`].

5) Re-run the install, selected the same installation directory. Skip the instance `configurator/wizard` at the end of the install.

6) Make sure the `../bin` directory gets added to the path. Verify it.

7) Manually run the instance `configurator/wizard`.
   Set the root password, port [`3306`].
   It will try to start it. Again, mine FAILED to start 
   [duh!  nothing new there!!!]

8) Now, manually edit the `my.ini` file in the install directory, and correct the `datadir` setting to be [`datadir="C:/Data/MySQL/"`] MATCH CAPITALIZATION !!!!

9) Verify the service is setup correctly via the command-prompt [`sc qc mysql <enter>`].
    Should look like:

```
C:\dev\cmdz>sc qc mysql

[SC] GetServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\apps\MySQL\MySQLServer-5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\apps\MySQL\MySQLServer-5.5\my.ini" MySQL
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : MySQL
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

10) Copy the contents of the default data-directory created under `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL` [basically everything in this directory to your desired data directory `c:\data\mysql`].  Make sure you get the `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\mysql` directory.  This has `host.frm` file, and others.
   You should end up with a directory now of `c:\data\MySQL\mysql...`

11) Rename the default directory 
      `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL`
   To
      `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQLxxx`
   So it cannot find it...

12) Say a quick prayer...

13) Give it a kick start from command line with [`net start mysql`]

That got it working for me...

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

in my case **innodb_data_home_dir** was no longer correct because I had shuffled some drive letters around when I added a new drive to my system

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have unzipped XAMPP ina a second disk on my installation, "F". When I tried to start as a service, the return was "1067". The solution was to edit my.ini, inserting the "f:" drive in the files lines. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem look like there is no data in the directory.
copy at least the mysql directory either from your previous directory or from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data .
And then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and **it was caused by non standard characters in the log files path**.
In order to fix that I found my.ini config file (in my case `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini`) and modified keys `slow_query_log_file` and `log-error`.
After that I managed to start MySQL service succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had chosen a custom path for my log-files in the MySQL installer. I had put the log-files in my user-folder `C:\Users\%MY_USERACCOUNT%\Documents\mysql-logs`, and by default, *NETWORK SERVICE* (or any other non-administrator useraccount in Windows) does not have access to a user's folder.

I fixed this by changing security options for the log-folder, giving modify rights read/write/modify rights to *NETWORK SERVICE*.

Answer (score 0):

I also get log  with Table *'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist*
if install MYSQL Server 5.1 by 'msiexec.exe' 
 DataDir I put as C:\MYSQL\MySQL_Server_5_1\data\

but to my surprise was create data in a C:\MYSQL\MySQL_Server_5_1\data\data

There are was add word **data** . So I change my.ini file from

```
datadir="C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5_1/Data/" .
```

to the

```
datadir="C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5_1/Data/data"
```

and then I can use 
 **net start MYSQL51**
and then **mysqld.exe run and appear in a Task Manager**

Answer (score 0):

when looked at mysql log (.err file under data folder), i could see the following

21:41:47 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

I realized i was starting the service while i plugged usb. To be honest, the problem was resolved after i restarted my machine followed by restarting the service. In addition i removed ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 files before my restart. Though the event logger indicated "InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information

> Blockquote

about forcing recovery.For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://www.mysql.com", i do not think so because i never changed any configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same error, below is the reason and solution that worked for me for mysql-5.7.14-winx64

reason: DATA folder to have some default folders and files which were missing

**solution**: delete everything from DATA folder, i assume its a fresh installation so backup anything that you need if at all. Then run this from the command prompt and it will create required files and folders
"mysqld --initialize --console"
now run "mysqld" and it should work well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had another MySQL version installed and running.
I found this by going into the mysql_error.log file.
I fix this by going to services and stopping the running MySQL version and setting up to a manual, and starting the mysql needed.

Answer (score 0):

...an old one... anyway I had the same issue with MariaDB

In my case most pathes contain special characters like: #
Wrapping pathes in my.ini in double quotes made the trick - e.g.

```
datadir="C:/#windata64/db/MariaDB/data"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in order to delete a heavy schema from mysql server, just went to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data and deleted relevant folder. But it was not being deleted because mysqld.exe was preventing it. so I stopped mysqld.exe, deleted the folder and then all the schemas went disappeared from the list in mysql workbench. No matter how much I tried to restart mysql service, it didnt unless I restored that folder from junk.
Hope it helps someone who tried the same shortcut as I did.

Answer (score 0):

I run MariaDB (MySQL compatible) on two machines locally. I'm not sure what prompted the error and nothing I tried worked. So I stopped the service, deleted everything in MariaDB's directory (except the data directory) and copied the files from my secondary machine and everything is working well enough as far as I can tell.

For a live server it'd be a bit different and a super-guru *might* be able to add an insight comment (e.g. something outside of the data directory might have something to do with preventing data corruption or indexes in example?). I would just stop the service and copy the entire directory once every month or so and then start the service again.

Answer (score 0):

Something I just discovered was that in the setup I choose InnoDB, whereas in fact all my existing databases were in MyIsam format. I uninstalled and then re-installed choosing MyIsam and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error log file was not there so I've created a folder for the error log path and opened the `my.ini` file:

```ini
log-error=D://logs//mysql//mysql_error.log
```

It is working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

**If you are trying to run MySql on a Windows 10 installation with a GPT partition, please try this:**

Todays systems are often running on a disk which is formatted in GPT. This is because Windows 10 needs such a partition to be installed. The problem is that MySql cant deal with this partition style and so it crashes. Here is my workaround:

- Create a virtual disk: [manual here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg318052(v=ws.10).aspx)
- Format this VHD with MBR
- Install MySql custom on your new VHD (dont forget to create a user for DB)

This should be it! :)

Reference Link:
[Issue with MySql installation on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809529/issue-with-mysql-installation-on-windows-10)