# MariaDB won't start

Tags: mysql, windows, mariadb

I'm starting MariaDB on windows 10. It installs fine, but when I try to start it with `net start mysql` on elevated command line I get this:

```
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.5>net start mysql
The MySQL service is starting.
The MySQL service could not be started.
A system error has occurred.
System error 1067 has occurred.
The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

here is the error file

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-01-22 16:23:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-22 16:23:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-22 16:23:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-22 16:23:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-22 16:23:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-22 16:23:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-01-22 16:23:10 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.0 started; log sequence number 61454; transaction id 21
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.5\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200122 16:23:11
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-01-22 16:23:11 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.5\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.5.0-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3333  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1067 error on attempt to start MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158965/1067-error-on-attempt-to-start-mysql)

Comment: thiis show no errors at all, check if service is already started.

Comment: Is the service running?